# How to generate all possible key-value combinations between a String and Array[String]

Tags: arrays, scala, combinations

I am very new to Scala and hence this might be a very basic question.

I have a variable "myArray" of type Array[(String, Array[String])]. The value of this array is

```
Array((1,Array(2, 3, 4)), (2,Array(1, 3, 4, 6, 7)), (3,Array(1, 2, 4, 5))).
```

If we think the first element for each tuple is a key ( e.g., in the tuple (1,Array(2, 3, 4)), 1 is the key) and rest is the value (e.g., Array(2, 3, 4)), I want to create an Array for which the elements will be all possible combination of key-value pairs for each corresponding key, where the value will be each element of the Array[String]

The result should look like

```
Array((1,Array(1,2)), (1,Array(1,3)), (1,Array(1,4)), (2,Array(2,1)), 
      (2,Array(2,3)), (2,Array(2,4)), ...., (3,Array(3,4)), (3,Array(3,5)))
```

Comment: This is just a variation of "Get all unique combinations", albeit in a language that I haven't seen an implementation for on SO. Still seems like a duplicate though.

Comment: I tried the following code. But is there any smarter way to do this

val array2 = array1.map(x => {
     val b = x._2
     val a = x._1
     val bsze = b.size
     for (i <- 0 to (bsze-1)) yield(a(0), b(i))
     } )

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try to highlight your code (use 4 space before typing code), so other users can read your question more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@wingedsubmariner is close, but in order to match @user3658637's weird requirements the mapping is:

```
for {
  (key, values) <- array
  value <- values
  yield (key,Array(key, value))     //> res1: Array[(Int, Array[Int])] = Array((1,Array(1, 2)), (1,Array(1, 3)), (1,
                                    //| Array(1, 4)), (2,Array(2, 1)), (2,Array(2, 3)), (2,Array(2, 4)), (2,Array(2,
                                    //|  6)), (2,Array(2, 7)), (3,Array(3, 1)), (3,Array(3, 2)), (3,Array(3, 4)), (3
                                    //| ,Array(3, 5)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If your array is in a value `array`:

```
for {
  (key, values) <- array
  value <- values
} yield (key, value)
```